# how to cast json to typescript object

Tags: typescript, mobx-state-tree

There initialized JSON data, I need to convert this as an type(mobx-state-tree) of object defined as belows,

```
 const resultData = [
  {
    survey_id: 9,
    title: 'Test Survey id9',
    is_anonymous: false,
    end_datetime: '2022-02-21T00:00:00+00:00',
    category: {
      full_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/trivie-eventcategory-dev/W2V38X/f868184aece546c9_11.png',
      is_archived: false,
      label: 'Survey',
    },
  },
]
```

Models:

```
import { Instance, types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

    export const SurveyAssignCategoryModel = types.model('SurveyAssignCategoryModel').props({
      full_url: types.string,
      is_archived: types.boolean,
      label: types.string,
    })
    
    export const GetAssignedSurveysForUserResponseModel = types
      .model('GetAssignedSurveysForUserResponseModel')
      .props({
        survey_id: types.number,
        title: types.string,
        is_anonymous: types.boolean,
        end_datetime: types.maybeNull(types.string),
        category: types.maybeNull(types.array(types.late(() => SurveyAssignCategoryModel))),
      })
```

Here is the error message in IDE (it has `category` underlined in the object literal):

> Type '{ full_url: string; is_archived: false; label: string; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IMSTArray<IModelType<{ full_url:
> ISimpleType; is_archived: ISimpleType; label:
> ISimpleType; }, {}, _NotCustomized, _NotCustomized>> &
> IStateTreeNode<...>'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'full_url' does not exist in type
> 'IMSTArray<IModelType<{ full_url: ISimpleType; is_archived:
> ISimpleType; label: ISimpleType; }, {},
> _NotCustomized, _NotCustomized>> & IStateTreeNode<...>'

how to cast and use this object properly?

[image]

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. If it *were* JSON, it would need to have `"` around the property names.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ty for stackoverflow recipe, edited post, its a parsed JSON data, would be glad to know if you have solution offer

Comment: @T.J.Crowder done...

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with `mobx-state-tree`, but I think it's error here:

```
...
category: types.maybeNull(types.array(types.late(...
```

`category` it's not `array` but I think `map` and here you don't need `late`.

try something this:

```
...
category: types.maybeNull(types.map(SurveyAssignCategoryModel))
```